# BootstrapDualListbox mostrar en la segunda lista

Tags: ajax, bootstrap, multiselect

espero me puedan ayudar ya que he pasado las últimas 4 horas buscando la manera correcta
de mostrar mi data en un bootstrapDualListbox de Bootstrap, específicamente en el helper2 cuando lo
recupero de la base con $.ajax

```
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select name="duallistbox[]" class="duallistbox" multiple="multiple">                   
                </select>
            </div>
            <!-- /.form-group -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: host() + "Controller/Metodo/",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "formulario": formulario }),
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        if (controlCarga(data)) {
            $.each(data[1], function (i, item) {
                $('select[name="duallistbox[]_helper2"]').append('<option value="' + item.value + '" data-sortindex="' + i + '">' + item.nombre + '</option>');
            });

            //$('select[name="duallistbox[]_helper2"]').bootstrapDualListbox('refresh', true);
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Error: ' + xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, entonces que es lo que quieres, cual es tu pregunta?

Comment: Lo que necesito es que al hacer click en un ítems de la lista no se borre, si no que debe desaparecer solo el que seleccione, tal cual como lo indicó en la imagen.